# JavaScript (Node.js) - JSON recursion extracting objects to array with order (faltten)

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, recursion, flatten

I have a JSON config file as follows:

```
var conf = [
    {
        "value": "baz",
        "threshold": 20,
        "other": 123
    },
    {
        "value": "mo",
        "other": 456,
        "child": {
            "value": "foo",
            "other": 789,
            "child": {
                "value": "larry",
                "other": 123
            }
        }
    }
];
```

I have a requirement to extract each of the objects and persist them together in order if they have child objects. For example, object 1 (baz) is stand alone. Object 2 (mo) will have two child objects. These 3 as a set must be extracted together.

There is no limit to the number of child objects.

Im attempting to persist each object using an array to maintain the order. So the required output would look like:

```
[[{"value":"baz","threshold":20,"other":123}],
[[{"value":"mo","other":456,"child":{"value":"foo","other":789,"child":{"value":"larry","other":123}}}],
[{"value":"foo","other":789,"child":{"value":"larry","other":123}}],
[{"value":"larry","other":123}]]]
```

A final requirement is to actually remove the child values from the parents so the output can actually be like:

```
    [
     [{"value":"baz","threshold":20,"other":123}],
     [
       [{"value":"mo","other":456}],
       [{"value":"foo","other":789}],
       [{"value":"larry","other":123}]
     ]
   ]
```

Ive been hung up on this for hours with little progress. I know I need to create a recursive function, push each node to an array, and then check for child object and repeat.

Heres what I have so far. My thinking is if I can take the array id each task is being pushed to (using a loop id), perhaps I can map that when the function is called again.

Appreciate any guidance.

var execSets = [];
function parser(tasks){

```
// an ordered array of task execution

for (let eachTask in tasks) {
    var taskSet = [];
    console.log("====================================");
    console.log(tasks[eachTask]);

    if(!tasks[eachTask].child && typeof(tasks[eachTask]) === 'object'){

        console.log(tasks[eachTask]);
        taskSet.push(tasks[eachTask]);
        execSets.push(taskSet);

    }

    if(tasks[eachTask].child){

        let childAlias = tasks[eachTask].child;
        delete tasks[eachTask].child;
        taskSet.push(tasks[eachTask]);

        execSets.push(taskSet);
        parser(childAlias);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The npm registry is your friend; try 'npm search flat,

There are a few modules that can help flatten a json object. For example https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat

Comment: No problem, sometimes making use of an existing solution is best

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using recursion. Here is my suggestion:

```
var conf = [
{
    "value": "baz",
    "threshold": 20,
    "other": 123
},
{
    "value": "mo",
    "other": 456,
    "child": {
        "value": "foo",
        "other": 789,
        "child": {
            "value": "larry",
            "other": 123
        }
    }
}
];


function getFlattenedObject(object){

   var response = [];   
   flatten(object, response, 0);    
   return response;

}


function flatten(object, array, index){

   if(!array[index]){
       array.push([]);
   }

   array[index].push(object);

   if(object.child){
        flatten(object.child, array, index + 1);
        object.child = undefined;
   }      
}

//Logs for comparison
console.dir(conf)
console.dir(getFlattenedObject(conf));
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the example - very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The result structure you are looking for wasn't "intuitive" and hence the solution has gotten a little ugly, but here is how you could use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan#readme) to answer your question

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = [{"value":"baz","threshold":20,"other":123},{"value":"mo","other":456,"child":{"value":"foo","other":789,"child":{"value":"larry","other":123}}}]

const fn = (haystack) => objectScan(['[*]', '**.child'], {
  filterFn: ({
    key: [id, ...p],
    value: { child, ...node },
    context
  }) => {
    if (!(id in context)) {
      context[id] = [];
    }
    context[id].push(child || p.length !== 0 ? [node] : node);
  }
})(haystack, []);

console.log(fn(data));
// => [ [ { value: 'baz', threshold: 20, other: 123 } ], [ [ { value: 'larry', other: 123 } ], [ { value: 'foo', other: 789 } ], [ { value: 'mo', other: 456 } ] ] ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)